# XE5, JNI - How would I add (install) JNI support to Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-xe5

I am looking to add JNI libraries into my XE5, but I had no luck.

When I call out to the units in the uses (eg. Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Net...) I get a message that XE5 can't resolve unit name.

I have located the JNI files I need (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\source\rtl\android), but I don't know how to link to them in XE5.

This is my first time in XE5 and I'm doing this for a school project, so please, be gentle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've already read this, but it served me no help as it didn't explain how to install the JNI libraries. Maybe it did, but my XE5 first-timer brain might have skipped over it. I'm doing this for a school project and I'm not that familiar with XE5, I've done Delphi programming only on Borlands Delphi.

I have located the JNI files I need (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\source\rtl\android), but I don't know how to link to them in XE5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **${BDSDIR}\Lib\${PLATFORM}\${Target}** to your library path, which in the case of an Android platform debug target will end up adding **C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\lib\android\debug** to the library path during a build; in the case of an Android release build it will automatically change to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\lib\android\release**.

Comment: Is it possible for me to have an application running on PC which communicates to my Android device via USB. For example, the data (string) written in the Edit box on PC to be transferred to Android.

Comment: I've answered the question you asked here. If you have a new question, create a new post and ask it there. You also might want to read [this help center topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).